# Stash/BitBucket prevents from committing if commit does not include JIRA number

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I'm not going to get a working solution but at least to get an answer if it is possible at all by Stash/Bitbucket. So my request is: We need to deploy some policy  for ourselves in the company not to allow engineer to commit if commit comment does not contain (best does not begin with) JIRA issue number. For instance:

```
TEST-1234 (Jira under which I'm doing a commit) Here's my code
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depending on your needs, maybe consider a solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077959/parse-branch-name-initiate-commit-with-name-in-the-commit-message/)?

Comment: @RomainValeri, thank you for the solution, it will try to adopt to project need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr use the add-on [Yet Another Commit Checker](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211854/yet-another-commit-checker) to enforce a regex, e.g. `[A-Z][A-Z]+-[0-9]+ .*`

Don't try to install your own script hooks via the on disk git repositories in Bitbucket Server. This *can be done*, but it's a) painful to audit (people have done this sort of thing, forgotten, and lost weeks trying to troubleshoot Bitbucket not knowing that git repos had been manually tampered with on disk) and b) dangerous, because Bitbucket Server intentionally applies a lot of specialised configuration and expects that end users are *not messing around with the raw git repos on disk*.

For what it's worth, I work for Atlassian's Premier Support team and supported Bitbucket Server for two years. You will be much, much better off with Yet Another Commit Checker.