# Rebase error while amending Git message for mulitple commits

Tags: git, git-bash

i want to change my commit messages, where i am following the [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commit-messages)

i gave below command to change my older and multiple commits

> git rebase -i HEAD~n

but i am getting below error

```
error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: Please commit or stash them.
```

i am not sure, why i am getting this error, where i need to change my commit message before pushing to bitbucket, not intended to stash or commit them .

i have 8 commits, which needs to be pushed.

EDIT :-

```
git status

$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 8 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    ABC.log
        modified:   src/test/java/com/elastic/nftqa/TestqaApplicationTests.java

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .settings/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")



Git push 
    remote: Push rejected.
    remote:
    remote: refs/heads/dev: f5b0790e1d5: No Jira Issue found in commit message
    remote:
    remote: refs/heads/dev: 8f27f788c4c: No Jira Issue found in commit message
    remote:
    remote: refs/heads/dev: 0dba081770e: No Jira Issue found in commit message
    remote:
    remote: refs/heads/dev: a3d6680c680: No Jira Issue found in commit message
    remote:
    remote: refs/heads/dev: 76cccb2cc1d: No Jira Issue found in commit message
```

Comment: Do you have unstaged changes? Does ```git status``` return "nothing to commit, working tree clean" ?

Comment: "i am not sure, why i am getting this error" Yes, you are sure why. It is because you have unstaged changes. You cannot do an interactive rebase if you have unstaged changes.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: As I mention in my answer: `git config --global rebase.autoStash true`, then rebase, making sure to add Jira in the messages, then push.

Answer (score 1):

> not intended to stash or commit them .

That does not leave you with many options!

I would prefer to use the `git config --global rebase.autoStash true` I mention in "[Can “git pull” automatically stash and pop pending changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)"

Do you `git rebase -i` without worrying about the stash step:  Git will stash and restore for you the files which are blocking the rebase.

Use at least [Git .210 (Q3 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38436051/6309) in order to be sure Git will restore autostash on abort.

The `git push` error message is another problem entirely, separate from the `git rebase`.
As illustrated in detail with "[pre-receive hook declined: No JIRA Issue found in commit message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54483430/6309)", make sure to add the Jira number in the edited commit message.